# What are possible ways to write 24/7 remote working game engine?

Tags: php, sockets

I am a beginner programmer that wants to write simple turn-based 2-player game.

The problem begins when the application of paired 2 players wants to communicate, I can write a simple server in C++ using sockets, but then people could play only while server is online.

I cant run my comp 24/7 so:

**Is it possible to use on-line free hosting (empty website + PHP parameters + PHP sockets + mySQL) as a game server?** I serached some sites but they allow only web hosting, they wont allow me to use it as game-phycics-computing-centre.

**What are other ways to write a server application that would run 24/7 (preferably for free)?**

**If I switched whole project to peer-2-peer, how should it work?** (the communication during match is extremely easy but ... how would players search for others? How would one player know that other player is online and challenge him a match?)

**Thanks for current answers, now I am just thinking about free sql database + p2p solution or any other that would work 24/7**

Comment: You can't use PHP is a game engine. It'd be slow as hell. However, you could just create a MySQL database on a server and only use that for online players. So your game simply sends a query to the server that the player is online. If game closes, send query for being offline. It's not fool proof. If the game crashes, the server won't receive an update on player being offline. You need to use a socket for that. But running a socket on a server, requires some sort of shell access with enough rights to start a socketserver. You probebly won't find that for free.

Comment: Technically you could make a workaround for it though. Make the client send a "player is offline query" towards the server if any player tries to connect with an online player but it doesn't respond. So if `Player A` tries to connect with `Player B`, but `Player B` doesn't respond, `Player A` sends a query to mysql that `Player B` is offline.

Comment: Thanks, I guess PHP is slow because its not compile-able.It seems I wont get any 24/7 networking application for free. I can allow each player to connect to database to set his presence online (other player could refreshs others) (I dont care about security now) and I guess free 24/7 databse is maximum I can get for free

Comment: Exactly. It'll work, but there are still issues you need to resolve. Like data traffic for example. Most free hosts will give you like 5GB of data traffic a month. If you query the MySQL server to much, you'll reach that limit far before the end of the month, which will render your game useless. For the time being, I'd add the abilty to "add friends" to your game so players can see eachother in case the server is down. That's only a temporary solution though. It's very unprofessional if the server is down all the time, and it'll cost you players in the end.

Comment: You could also use the MySQL server for player registration only. That way each client only queries the server once to "update all registered players" and to update their own profiles IP address so they don't get outdated. It would generate far less data traffic and the client can simply ping ports to see who's online / offline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I could come up with works as follows:

1. Have a MySQL database to register users. Stuff like a name and their IP address.
2. When client starts, it queries for the entire user database and saves / updates them locally.
3. Next the client queries the server to update the players own IP address. This so any other clients receive their latest IP address.
4. From this point on, the client uses it's own ports to ping the IP addresses saved locally so it knows who's online and who isn't. Or something like that. I'm not to formilliar with p2p protocols.
5. Lastly, have the client query the server to update the users only once per hour or longer, so they receive updated IP addresses that happened while they were already playing.

Doing it like this will save you A LOT of data traffic, while still keeping your multi-player game viable to play.

Comment: I think I can even remove whole server application and make everything to go between sql and clients,  and just add "refresh online players" button in the game. Each player can check if are there any other online players and ask them for a match. The match state would be held only on the players app but as I said already, I dont care about security for such simple only4fun project.

Answer (score 0):

In order to run a server application, you probably need some computing power with internet connectivity. In the following few lines I try to list a few free options (presuming this is what you are looking for).

As you did not specify details about your situation, here are some cases:

- General: you can try [AWS Free Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/), where

  > After creating your AWS account you can use any of the 21 products and  services, <strike>listed below</strike>, for free within certain usage limits.

  In order to make the answer sound less of a cheap ad, you could also try  [Microsoft Azure Free Trial](https://azure.microsoft.com/hu-hu/pricing/free-trial/) what is much like AWS, but only for 1 month.
- You have nowhere stated, but in case you are an official student, the GitHub Student Developer Pack offers you $100 in platform credit for DigitalOcean

Comment: "some computing power" - I expect maximum of 10-20 players, I guess its nothing in today's world

Comment: What information do you mean by "details"?

Comment: Still, you probably need somewhere to run your program, I guess

Comment: By details, I mean: what kind of a game are we talking about. What kind of requirements do you (= does the game) have?

Comment: Its a card turn based game, I use SFML library for C++, its just an example game that I can learn programming through making it. I also considered giving all possible cards to all players upon registration (its 100% for fun, not to earn). I suppose we dont have to care about hardware, I tested some parts already and had 5000 FPS.